# How to detect a click on irregular image drawn on a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

actually i am drawing an image on a panel.the image was in irrigular shape. For a mouse click i want to display a message wheather the click was done on the image or on the panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Region Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.aspx) and its [Intersect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wysx694.aspx) in order to achieve your goal, but probably there exist better solutions. However, until you found them, try the following one based on the example of capturing mouse point in ellipse drawed on the panel.

Declare fields:

```
private readonly GraphicsPath _graphicsPath;
private readonly Region _region;
private readonly Graphics _panelGraphics;
```

Initialize above fields:

```
_graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();
_graphicsPath.AddEllipse(100, 100, 100, 100); // Path that contains simple ellipse. You can add here more shapes and combine them in similar manner as you draw them.
_region = new Region(_graphicsPath); // Create region, that contains Intersect method.
_panelGraphics = panel1.CreateGraphics(); // Graphics for the panel.
```

Panel paint event handle:

```
private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    _panelGraphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 100, 100, 100, 100); // Draw your structure.
}
```

Panel mouse down event handle:

```
private void panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var cursorRectangle = new Rectangle(e.Location, new Size(1, 1)); // We need rectangle for Intersect method.
    var copyOfRegion = _region.Clone(); // Don't break original region.
    copyOfRegion.Intersect(cursorRectangle); // Check whether cursor is in complex shape.

    Debug.WriteLine(copyOfRegion.IsEmpty(_panelGraphics) ? "Miss" : "In");
}
```

Comment: sorry to say ..it was not working,i am drawing an image on apanel with some zoom level,the image will not cover the whole panel,so how to detect my mouse click if it was done on the image or the remaining area with in the panel,plz help me..

Comment: @user2095270: If that is just an image from a file that you are drawing (not your own draft, drawing) then use the scenario from my second answer. This answer is checked on my machine and it works but only if you are drawing structure, that you can add to *GraphicsPath*.

Answer (score 0):

Below is scenario for drawing just image on a panel:

Declare fields:

```
private readonly Bitmap _image;
private readonly Graphics _panelGraphics;
```

Initialize fields:

```
_image = new Bitmap(100, 100); // Image and panel have same size.
var imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(_image);
imageGraphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 10, 10, 50, 50); // Some irregular image.

panel2.Size = new Size(100, 100);
panel2.BackColor = Color.Transparent; // Panel's background color is transparent.
_panelGraphics = panel2.CreateGraphics();
```

Panel paint event handle:

```
private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    _panelGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(_image, 0, 0);
}
```

Panel mouse down event handle:

```
private void panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(_image.GetPixel(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y).A != 0 ? "In" : "Miss");
}
```

Comment: The above scenario requires, that panel's *BackColor* is set to *Transparent* and also the area on the image, that not belongs to the shape is transparent.